# Including not found criteria in the result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
select  BUnit, value from myTable where BUnit in (555,556,557,558)
```

and these values for Bunit are constructed dynamically, ie. a program builds queries on demand, and they won't always select these numbers.

A possible query result would be

```
Bunit            value
556              10.2
558              5.18
```

However, I would like to construct a select statement to return

```
Bunit            value
556              10.2
558              5.18  
555              NULL
557              NULL
```

I am not allowed to create tables (temporary or not) and to create procedures. How can I do it?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by "values for BUnit are constructed dynamically"?   To me the query looks correct given the data you have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a table with the criteria, and join on that:

```
select criteria.BUnit, t.value 
from (
    select 555 as BUnit from dual
    union select 556 from dual
    union select 557 from dual
    union select 558 from dual
) criteria
left join myTable t 
    on t.BUnit = criteria.BUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a temporary table, you can't since you must find a way to put all the values of `BUnit` into a table of some kind and then join `myTable` against that table to get the `NULL` values.

You could generate the SQL dynamically in your app and send down something like this:

```
select 555, (select value from myTable where BUnit = 555)
from dual
union
select 556, (select value from myTable where BUnit = 556)
from dual
...
```

But before you attempt this, I suggest that you create the desired result structure in your app and then fill in the values you get from the database.